# Nginxが起動しなくなりました。nginx.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded

Tags: centos, nginx

```
# systemctl start nginx.service
```

> Job for nginx.service failed because a configured resource limit was
>   exceeded. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe"
>   for details.

---

```
# systemctl status nginx.service
```

> ● nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server    Loaded:
>   loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   disabled) 
>      Active: failed (Result: resources) since

---

```
# journalctl -xe
```

> -- The result is failed.
>   -- systemd[1]: Failed to start Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
>   -- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>   -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

---

```
# systemctl status systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
```

> ● systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service - Cleanup of Temporary Directories   
>   Loaded: loaded
>   (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service; static;
>   vendor preset: disabled)    Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since
>   日付; 1 day 2h ago
>        Docs: man:tmpfiles.d(5)
>              man:systemd-tmpfiles(8)   Process: 12692 ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemd-tmpfiles --clean (code=exited,
>   status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 12692 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> 日付 systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...  
>    日付 systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...

---

```
# less /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
```

・編集した覚えはないので、多分デフォルトのままだと思います

> [Unit] Description=Cleanup of Temporary Directories
>   Documentation=man:tmpfiles.d(5) man:systemd-tmpfiles(8)
>   DefaultDependencies=no Conflicts=shutdown.target
>   After=systemd-readahead-collect.service
>   systemd-readahead-replay.service local-fs.target time-sync.target
>   Before=shutdown.target
>
> [Service] Type=oneshot ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemd-tmpfiles --clean
>   IOSchedulingClass=idle

---

**環境**
・Nginx
・CentOS7

Comment: `/var/log/nginx/error.log`に何かエラーは出力されていないでしょうか?

Comment: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.serviceがfailとでてますね。`systemctl status systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service` をすると、結果はどうなりますか？

Comment: /var/log/nginx/error.logに表示されているエラーは「PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused」や「 [alert] 1767#1767: worker process 1768 exited on signal 9」などです

Comment: systemctl status systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service結果は、本文に追記しました

Comment: 何度もすみません。`journalctl -f`で確認した場合に、他のエラーなどは出力されていないでしょうか?

Comment: journalctl -f 実行すると 以下内容が順不同でループ表示され続けます。画面が流れていくので全てを確認したわけではないのですが、他のメッセージは表示されていないと思います。
Failed to start Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service failed.
start request repeated too quickly for systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service.他に一つだけsystemd-journal[360]: Suppressed 150726 messages from / というメッセージが表示されていました

Comment: すみません。お手数おかけしました。ログからわかりそうにないですね。すみませんでした。あとはメモリやCPU、ディスクなどの使用率でしょうか。

Comment: `/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service`の中身も見せてもらえますか？

Comment: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service内容を本文に追記しました

Comment: systemd 配下のサービスの設定の確認は `systemctl cat <サービス名>` を使いましょう。`/etc/systemd/system` 下のファイルによる上書き設定とマージした内容を確認できます。また、設定変更するのに `(/usr)/lib/systemd/system` 下のファイルは編集してはいけません。`systemctl edit <サービス名>` で `/etc/systemd/system` 下のファイルを編集するようにしましょう。

Answer (score 1):

とりあえずOS再起動したら、nginx起動できるようになりました。

---

この投稿は @re9 さん自身による質問本文への追記内容から転記しました。